Como puedo generar un apk en react native
hola buenas realice un proyecto con react-native y backend en python, realice el build con la documentacion de expo pero al instalar la app en mi dispositivo o telefono la app no se abre. al generar el build con EAS Build no me genera ningun error. Localmente la app si me abre etc.. pero necesito saber porque no se abre, hay alguna herramienta o algo para saber si se compilo con errores para saber donde esta el error. Aqui esta la configuracion de mi app para que me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias
App.json
{
  "expo": {
     "name": "FRONT_REACT_NATIVE_2",
     "slug": "lectororm",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "orientation": "portrait",
     "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
     "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
     "splash": {
        "image": "./assets/splash.png",
        "resizeMode": "contain",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
     },
     "plugins": [
        [
           "expo-camera",
           {
              "cameraPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera",
              "microphonePermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your microphone",
              "recordAudioAndroid": true
           }
        ]
      ],
      "assetBundlePatterns": [
         "**/*"
      ],
      "ios": {
           "infoPlist": {
           "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access the camera."
            }
      },
      "android": {
           "adaptiveIcon": {
           "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
           "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "permissions": [
          "CAMERA",
          "RECORD_AUDIO",
          "android.permission.CAMERA"
      ],
      "package": "com.lucascardemil.lectororm"
    },
    "web": {
        "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
        "eas": {
              "projectId": "9ba8dd08-af02-49e0-b443-cbdeed3ec0ac"
         }
    },
    "owner": "lucascardemil"
 }
}

eas.json
{
   "cli": {
        "version": ">= 3.0.0"
    },
    "build": {
         "development": {
              "distribution": "internal",
    "android": {
          "buildType": "apk",
          "env": {
                 "EXPO_Url": "https://back-orm.onrender.com"
           }
     }
},
"preview": {
  "distribution": "internal",
  "android": {
    "buildType": "apk",
    "env": {
      "EXPO_Url": "https://back-orm.onrender.com"
    }
  }
},
"production": {
  "distribution": "internal",
  "android": {
    "buildType": "apk",
    "env": {
      "EXPO_Url": "https://back-orm.onrender.com"
    }
  }
}
   },
  "submit": {
     "production": {}
  }
}


usa "adb logcat" para ver los logs de tu dispositivo mientras intentas abrir la aplicacion, si tenes ios creo que la app se llama xcode

gracias amigo, estoy viendo la terminal en android studio y me aperecen los errores.
